# Apply same style to all tr and td of multiple table having same parent CSS class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to merge the following two css classes:

```
.addActivityTable table tr {
    border: none;
}

.addActivityTable table td {
    border: none;
}
```

as

```
.addActivityTable table tr, table td {
    border: none;
}
```

It is not taking any effect, also I have tried:

```
.addActivityTable table tr, td {
    border: none;
}
```

This also doesn't work. Is there any way to merge these?

If someone point me a good article or blog on these kind of css selectors, it would be helpful to me to learn.

Comment: `.addActivityTable table tr, .addActivityTable table td`...or shortened to `.addActivityTable tr, .addActivityTable td` since presumably there is always a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
.addActivityTable table tr, .addActivityTable table td {
    border: none;
}
```

or

```
.addActivityTable tr, .addActivityTable td {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 In my case the `.activityTable` itself is a class of a table. I just want to apply `border: none` to all those `tr` and `td` which belong to the sub-table of `activityTable`. Your first solution works like a charm. Could you please tell me about some article on css selectors?

Comment: This is a good one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Happy to help, Tapas Bose.

Answer (score 0):

```
.addActivityTable tr, .addActivityTable td {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it'll help you. Just remove the table

```
  .addActivityTable tr, td {
    border: none;
  }
```

Comment: That will match *all* TD elements...probably not the desired effect based on the original selector.

Comment: Think of it this way. The above says, "Set border to none on all table rows that are children of a container with the class addActivityTable and set border to none on all table cells anywhere in the site."